# Forest trees on the same line

Tags: forest

I need to put two trees (package forest) side by side, but I haven't find any info on the package documentation.

```
\begin{forest}
[P1
   [SN
      [N[Mary]]]

   [VP
      [V[loves]]
      [N[Luke]]
]]

\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
[P2
   [NP
      [Pro[This]]]
   [VP
      [V[is]]
      [NP
      [Det[a]]
      [N[xx]]
]]]

\end{forest}
```

Comment: You can put every `forest` environment in a separate `minipage` environment.

Comment: Don't leave an empty line between the two `forest` environment: a blank line makes a paragraph end. To TeX's eyes, a `forest` is just a big letter.

Comment: Note that you cannot leave empty lines *within* a `forest` environment. You code in its current form will cause errors during compilation, even if with the correct preamble.

Comment: You can find info and documentation for all packages on CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest

Comment: For center alignment see [diagrams - Tree, then arrow, then tree - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320312/tree-then-arrow-then-tree/320316#320316)

Answer (score 14):

No need of phantoms: use `adjustbox` and its features for moving boxes around. A tree made by `forest` has its reference point at the bottom, we can align at the top with `valign=t`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest,adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{forest}
[P1
   [SN
      [N[Mary]]]
   [VP
      [V[loves]]
      [N[Luke]]
]]
\end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}\qquad
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{forest}
[P2
   [NP
      [Pro[This]]]
   [VP
      [V[is]]
      [NP
      [Det[a]]
      [N[xx]]
]]]
\end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use the `baseline` option (*i.e.*, `\begin{forest} baseline`)? Then you don't have to use `adjustbox` at all.

Comment: @AdamLiter That's covered by Qrrbrbirlbel

Comment: Ah, fair point. Didn't scroll that far down. `:)`

Answer (score 11):

You have two errors in your code that exclude the possibility to have both trees on the same horizontal line:

1. You have an empty line between the `forest` environments which TeX interprets as a new paragraph. Remove that empty line or insert a `%`.
2. Your `forest` environments has empty lines in it. This prevents TeX from compiling your code at all as it breaks the `forest` parser. The same rule as for above is valid.

You now have both `forest` trees on the same horizontal line. As TeX sees the trees (the underlying TikZ pictures) as two big box which have their baseline at the bottom the roots of the trees are not vertically aligned.

You can change this with the `baseline` option (a `forest` option here, there also exist a TikZ `baseline` option). At any node you use the `baseline` option, the baseline of the whole tree is set. In this way, you can give the `baseline` option to the `VP` node in the first tree and the `Det` node in the second tree to vertically align the pictures at these node. Is the option given as an option to the `forest` environment, the option is applied to the root node.

If you want both trees in one picture (to make it easy to draw between them), the [`phantom` option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147586/16595) might be helpful. You may need to include a few `phantom` levels to align the sub-trees at different levels as in the example before.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} baseline
[P1
   [SN
      [N[Mary]]]
   [VP
      [V[loves]]
      [N[Luke]]
]]
\end{forest}\hspace{1cm}
\begin{forest} baseline
[P2
   [NP
      [Pro[This]]]
   [VP
      [V[is]]
      [NP
      [Det[a]]
      [N[xx]]
]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

It's a little bit tricky. You draw both trees as branches from a `phantom` parent. This idea has been stolen from several examples in `forest` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest.pdf).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[, phantom, s sep = 1cm
 [P1
    [SN [N  [Mary]]]
    [VP [V  [loves]]
        [N  [Luke]]]
 ]
 [P2
   [NP [Pro [This]]]
   [VP [V [is]]
       [NP [Det [a]]
       [N  [xx]]]]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Ignasi's idea, you can draw a "phantom" edge that makes the shorter tree to have the same levels as the taller tree. And this allows for two `forest` environments.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[P1
   [SN
      [N[Mary]]]
   [VP
      [V[loves]]
      [N[Luke
        [,no edge] % phantom edge to increase tree level
      ]]
]]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
[P2
   [NP
      [Pro[This]]]
   [VP
      [V[is]]
      [NP
      [Det[a]]
      [N[xx]]
]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]