# Eliminate distance from phantom node in forest

Tags: vertical-alignment, linguistics, forest, gb4e

[Ignasi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147586/32888) to [Forest trees on the same line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146568/32888) shows how to effectively draw two trees in the same `forest` environment using the `phantom` trick noted in the `forest` documentation.

Doing this, however, leads to extra vertical distance in the tree(s), which is quite noticeable when aligned with something else. For example, putting the trees inside of an `\ex` leads to the "top" of the trees starting below the example number.

[image]

Is there a way to eliminate this extra distance so that the "tops" of the two trees are  aligned with the example number?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex{
        \begin{forest} baseline
            [, phantom, s sep = 3em
                [asdf
                    [a]
                    [b]
                ]
                [asdf
                    [a]
                    [b]
                ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    }
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it understand `overlay` option in the phantom node? (On the phone, no TeX sorry)

Comment: @percusse I'm not sure, to be honest. A quick search through the `forest` documentation returns nothing for the word "overlay".

Comment: `phantom` means adding a phantom node with no visible connections to the roots of the two visible trees. This node is placed on the baseline as requested. Now you know why `adjustbox` can be useful, don't you? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg True, though I was ultimately hoping things could be in the same `forest` environment to make it easier to draw arrows from one tree to the other.

Comment: Just add next to the phantom option. If it goes up then good :)

Comment: @percusse It seems that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood but could you not do something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex{
        \begin{forest}
          for tree={
            where level=0{
              for children={%
                l sep=0pt,
                baseline},
            }{},
          },
            [, phantom, s sep = 3em
                [asdf
                    [a]
                    [b]
                ]
                [asdf
                    [a]
                    [b]
                ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    }
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image: children on baseline]

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Thanks cfr! For some reason, I could never get the `l sep` key to work, but now I can't remember what I tried. I deleted the files. Guess I should have read the manual more closely.

Comment: @AdamLiter I always try to use it on the wrong level and can then never figure out why it seems to have no effect... In this case, though, if you left `baseline` applying to the phantom node, I couldn't get it to work.