# How can I vertically center forest trees?

Tags: vertical-alignment, forest

I wanted to typeset

[image]

So, I wrote (derivation of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302713/82730)

```
\documentclass[a4size]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% forest
\usepackage{forest}
% parsing tree
\forestset{
  declare toks={wff}{},
  declare toks={connective}{},
  declare dimen register={parsing tree sep},
  parsing tree sep=7.5pt,
  parsing tree/.style={
    % append the current root to a new phantom root.
    for root'={
      replace by={[,phantom,append=!last dynamic node]}
    },
    for tree={
      math content,
      parent anchor=children,
      child anchor=parent,
      inner sep=0pt,
      if n children=1{!first.before packing=calign with current edge}{},
      delay={
        content=\circ,
        insert before/.wrap pgfmath arg={
          [##1,no edge,math content,anchor=base east, before computing xy={
            s/.pgfmath={s("!n")-parsing_tree_sep}}]
        }{wff},
        if connective={}{connective/.option=wff}{},
        insert after/.wrap pgfmath arg={
          [##1,no edge,math content,anchor=base west, before computing xy={
            s/.pgfmath={s("!p")+parsing_tree_sep}}]
        }{connective}
      }
    }
  },
  default preamble={parsing tree,baseline}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \fbox{
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=M}
      \begin{forest}
        [,wff=1,connective=\chi]
      \end{forest}
      \qquad
      \begin{forest}
        [,wff=m+3,connective=\neg [,wff=m,connective=\chi]]
      \end{forest}
      \qquad
      \begin{forest}
        [,wff=m+n+3,connective=\neg [,wff=m,connective=\chi]
        [,wff=n,connective=\chi]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{adjustbox}
  }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which was rendered as

[image]

The tree at the left is not vertically centered, but it's at the top.
How can I vertically center the trees?

Comment: Try to put all of them in separate boxes.    `\begin{adjustbox}{valign=M} <content> \end{adjustbox}\qquad\begin{adjustbox}{valign=M} <content> \end{adjustbox}\qquad\begin{adjustbox}{valign=M} <content> \end{adjustbox}`.

Comment: @azetina Your suggestion works, but I don't know why it works. Can you explain?

Comment: What happens here is that you are creating 3 boxes each of which can now have varied alignments. Unlike your first case, there is only one box but nothing to reference alignment with hence leaving it to top alignment.

Comment: @azetina Why don't you answer this question? I'll choose it.

Comment: Somewhat related to [Forest trees on the same line - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146568/forest-trees-on-the-same-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As defined, there is only one box and no other reference for alignment hence all trees are top-aligned. Choosing to put each tree on separate boxes and choosing the middle alignment, `M` the vertical center (equal height and depth), we obtain the desired result. Something like:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=M} <content> \end{adjustbox}\qquad\begin{adjustbox}{valign=M} <content> \end{adjustbox}\qquad\begin{adjustbox}{valign=M} <content> \end{adjustbox}
```

Here is mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4size]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% forest
\usepackage{forest}
% parsing tree
\forestset{
  declare toks={wff}{},
  declare toks={connective}{},
  declare dimen register={parsing tree sep},
  parsing tree sep=7.5pt,
  parsing tree/.style={
    % append the current root to a new phantom root.
    for root'={
      replace by={[,phantom,append=!last dynamic node]}
    },
    for tree={
      math content,
      parent anchor=children,
      child anchor=parent,
      inner sep=0pt,
      if n children=1{!first.before packing=calign with current edge}{},
      delay={
        content=\circ,
        insert before/.wrap pgfmath arg={
          [##1,no edge,math content,anchor=base east, before computing xy={
            s/.pgfmath={s("!n")-parsing_tree_sep}}]
        }{wff},
        if connective={}{connective/.option=wff}{},
        insert after/.wrap pgfmath arg={
          [##1,no edge,math content,anchor=base west, before computing xy={
            s/.pgfmath={s("!p")+parsing_tree_sep}}]
        }{connective}
      }
    }
  },
  default preamble={parsing tree,baseline}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \fbox{
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=M}
      \begin{forest}
        [,wff=1,connective=\chi]
      \end{forest}
    \end{adjustbox}
      \qquad
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=M}
      \begin{forest}
        [,wff=m+3,connective=\neg [,wff=m,connective=\chi]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{adjustbox}
      \qquad
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=M}
      \begin{forest}
        [,wff=m+n+3,connective=\neg [,wff=m,connective=\chi]
        [,wff=n,connective=\chi]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{adjustbox}
  }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Other methods involve using a table format. Something like:

```
\begin{tabular}{m{0.25\textwidth}m{0.25\textwidth}m{0.25\textwidth}@{}m{0pt}@{}}
  \begin{forest}
    [,wff=1,connective=\chi]
  \end{forest}
  &
  \begin{forest}
    [,wff=m+3,connective=\neg [,wff=m,connective=\chi]]
  \end{forest}
  &
  \begin{forest}
    [,wff=m+n+3,connective=\neg [,wff=m,connective=\chi]
    [,wff=n,connective=\chi]]
  \end{forest}
  &
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Do you mean putting each forest tree in a table cell?

Comment: Yes. That is a different approach. :)

Answer (score 5):

You do not need different boxes etc. You just need to remove `baseline` and use TikZ's `baseline` option to centre the trees vertically. For example,

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% forest
\usepackage{forest}
% parsing tree
\forestset{
  declare toks={wff}{},
  declare toks={connective}{},
  declare dimen register={parsing tree sep},
  parsing tree sep=7.5pt,
  parsing tree/.style={
    % append the current root to a new phantom root.
    for root'={
      replace by={[,phantom,append=!last dynamic node]}
    },
    for tree={
      math content,
      parent anchor=children,
      child anchor=parent,
      inner sep=0pt,
      if n children=1{!first.before packing=calign with current edge}{},
      delay={
        content=\circ,
        insert before/.wrap pgfmath arg={
          [##1,no edge,math content,anchor=base east, before computing xy={
            s/.pgfmath={s("!n")-parsing_tree_sep}}]
        }{wff},
        if connective={}{connective/.option=wff}{},
        insert after/.wrap pgfmath arg={
          [##1,no edge,math content,anchor=base west, before computing xy={
            s/.pgfmath={s("!p")+parsing_tree_sep}}]
        }{connective}
      }
    },
    /tikz/baseline=(current bounding box.center)
  },
  default preamble={parsing tree}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \fbox{
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=M}
      \begin{forest}
        [,wff=1,connective=\chi]
      \end{forest}
      \qquad
      \begin{forest}
        [,wff=m+3,connective=\neg [,wff=m,connective=\chi]]
      \end{forest}
      \qquad
      \begin{forest}
        [,wff=m+n+3,connective=\neg [,wff=m,connective=\chi]
        [,wff=n,connective=\chi]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{adjustbox}
  }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: without boxes]

Note that `a4size` is not a valid option so I've removed it as it makes no difference. Perhaps you meant `a4paper`? In that case, you should be sure to load something like `geometry` with a standard class.

Comment: Totally forgot about TikZ internals. Great job. I only dealt with the issue in terms of the boxes.

Comment: @azetina Well, your solution works, which is always good. I just thought this was a bit easier/more straightforward.

Comment: It took a while to wrap my mind around `/tikz/baseline=(current bounding box.center)`. What a monster TikZ is.